# Calculations from db values perl cgi

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

I am trying to fetch calculate the gpa of a student by fetching their grade and the number of credits their class is and calculating it. I am having an issue where it is not calculating the creditsEarned and GPA properly. For the grade of U or F the credits earned should be 0 but that is not what the output is. I am not sure what is wrong with my statements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#This is going to be the user login check and will set a cookie

use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);

use strict;

#Connection error 
sub showErrorMsgAndExit {
    print header(), start_html(-title=>shift);
    print (shift);
    print end_html();
    exit;
}

#Connecting to the database
my $dbUsername = "root";
my $dbPassword = "password";

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:f18final:localhost";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, {PrintError => 0});

#error checking
if(!$dbh) {
    print header(), start_html(-title=>"Error connecting to DB");
    print ("Unable to connec to the database");
    print end_html();
    exit;
}

print header;
print start_html(-title=>'Edit Classes');

#Need to execute sql command and then iterate row by row
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblclasses";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

my $passedCredits = 0;
my $attemptedCredits = 0;
my $totalHonor = 0;
my $gpa = 0.000;


##SSSssssssearch part


print "<table border=solid 1px>"; #start of table
print "<tr><th>Class Name</th><th>Department</th><th>Class Number</th><th>Grade</th><th>Credits</th>";
print "</tr>";
while( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "<tr><td>";
    print $row[1];
    print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print $row[2];
    print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print $row[3];
    print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print $row[4];
    print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print $row[5];
    print "</td>";

    $attemptedCredits = $attemptedCredits + $row[5];
    if($row[4] == 'A' || $row[4] == 'a') {
        $passedCredits = $passedCredits + $row[5];
        $gpa = $gpa + (4 * $row[5]);
    }
    elsif($row[4] == 'B' || $row[4] == 'b') {
        $passedCredits = $passedCredits + $row[5];
        $gpa = $gpa + (3 * $row[5]);
    }
    elsif($row[4] == 'C' || $row[4] == 'c') {
        $passedCredits = $passedCredits + $row[5];
        $gpa = $gpa + (2 * $row[5]);
    }
    elsif($row[4] == 'D' || $row[4] == 'd') {
        $passedCredits = $passedCredits + $row[5];
        $gpa = $gpa + (1 * $row[5]);
    }
    elsif($row[4] == 'F' || $row[4] == 'f') {

    }
    elsif($row[4] == 'S' || $row[4] == 's') {
        $passedCredits = $passedCredits + $row[5];
    }
    elsif($row[4] == 'U' || $row[4] == 'u') {

    }

    #calculate

    print "</tr>";

}


print "</table>";

#Need to make a table and populate it with text boxes of all the class data


print "</table>"; #End of table

$gpa = $gpa / $attemptedCredits;

##RReturn values
print qq{
<table border = '1px solid'>
<tr>
<td>
Attempted Credits
</td>
<td>
Passed Credits
</td>
<td>
GPA
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
$attemptedCredits
</td>
<td>
$passedCredits
</td>
<td>
$gpa
</td>
</tr>
</table>
};
print "<form action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/actions.pl method = 'post' >";
print "<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'More Options'>";
print "</form>";
print "<form action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/searchingTran.pl method = 'post' >";
print "<input type = 'text' name = 'search' size = '25'><br>";
print "<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Search'>";
print "</form>";
print end_html();
```

Here is my output[image]

Also is there a way to print GPA out to three decimal places?

Comment: FYI, you appear to have accidentally pasted your code twice in the question. I have edited it to remove the duplicate copy. Please double-check to verify that I didn't accidentally change it into something other than your actual code while doing so.

Comment: Please don't use a) the HTML generation functions from CGI.pm (like `start_html()` and `end_html()`) or b) raw HTML in your Perl code. [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) will show you some better alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For the grade of U or F the credits earned should be 0 but that is not what the output is.

When you generate the output, you are printing the content of `$row[5]` before even looking at what the grade was.  To display it correctly as 0, you will need to check the grade first and then print either `0` (if the grade was "F" or "U") or `$row[5]` (if the grade was anything else).

In real-world code, I would recommend using a templating system (such as [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template)) instead of printing out HTML directly, which would help to avoid this sort of mistake, but I see that this looks like a homework assignment and I doubt that using alternative methods like that would be within the boundaries of the assignment.

> Also is there a way to print GPA out to three decimal places?

Use `printf` or `sprintf`:

```
$gpa = sprintf('%0.3f', $gpa / $attemptedCredits);
```